# what is difference between transfer event of Mint function and Transfer function of ERC20 Smart Contract?

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js, erc20, openzeppelin

what is difference between transfer event of Mint function and Transfer function of ERC20 Smart Contract ?

I know that in Transfer event of Mint a from address is `address(0)` while in Transfer there is address of sender but not zero. I am expecting a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

The Transfer event accepts 3 params: token sender, recipient, and amount.

> *A token contract which creates new tokens SHOULD trigger a Transfer event with the `_from` address set to `0x0` when tokens are created.*

Source: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20

This is the standardized approach to emitting events when minting tokens.

You can also emit custom events on top of that. For example:

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 amount);
event Mint(uint256 amount, uint256 timestamp);

function mint(uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
     balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
     totalSupply += amount;
     emit Transfer(address(0x0), msg.sender, amount);
     emit Mint(amount, block.timestamp);
}
```